# Perl: How to get awk output from variable

Tags: perl

I am getting syntax error for awk.

```
value = a|b|c|d|e|F|g|h 

my $record =  `$value | awk -F "|" '{print $5}'`;
```

Thanks,

Comment: what error? What result would you expect? What do you get?

Comment: I want e as a result .. It showing awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `a' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: and if you would actually wrap your string into quotes?

Comment: I didn't get it . I am getting values in variable from which I need the 5th fields to be be print. Values are seperated by "|".

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I cannot do like this was as Value is variable. I have also tried using system("echo $value | awk -F "|" '{print $5}'"}; but not working ...

Comment: If you want an explanation for an error, then it's always a good idea to tell us exactly what the error message is.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have notified you that you were using Perl's `$5`, not awk's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're ever tempted to call awk from Perl then you're almost certainly doing something wrong. Perl can do pretty much everything that awk can do - and do it more efficiently and more portably.

```
my $value = 'a|b|c|d|e|F|g|h';

my $record =  (split /\|/, $value)[4]; # 4, not 5 as Perl arrays are zero-indexed
```

Comment: Really not genius, I'm afraid. Very basic Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 my $record = ( split /\|/, 'a|b|c|d|e|F|g|h' )[4];
```

With `$value`:

```
my $record = ( split /\|/, $value )[4];
```

Or there's even this:

```
my ( undef, undef, undef, undef, $record )  = split /\|/, $value;
```

Shelling to awk to *split*, is like not even trying Perl.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... Value is variable

Comment: @user -- just sub $value for the literal 'a|b|c...'.  I don't think you need to call awk.

Comment: While I understand why it's considered a good idea to use forward slashes in the split pattern argument, I have to admit that I prefer to use `split '\|', $stringtosplit;` in this particular situation. I like to avoid 'leaning toothpick syndrome'. I wouldn't argue about it in a professional code review however. :-)

Comment: @Sue Spence, `split m{\|}` and `split qr{\|}` avoid the LTS without pretending it's not a regex pat.

Comment: @ikegami That is hardly pretending it's not a regex pattern. It's simply a supported, readable way to provide a regex pattern to the function. See `perldoc -f split`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you were at the shell prompt, you'd use the following:

```
echo 'a|b|c|d|e|F|g|h' | awk -F "|" '{print $5}'
```

But you're executing the following (assuming Perl's `$5` is uninitialized):

```
a|b|c|d|e|F|g|h | awk -F "|" '{print }'
```

(Didn't you try printing out the command you were executing when noticed it wasn't working?)

Fix:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $cmd = shell_quote('echo', $value)
   .      ' | '
   .      shell_quote('awk', '-F', '|', '{print $5}');

my $fifth_field = `$cmd`;
```

Of course, it's much simpler to use `split` and a list slice.

```
my $fifth_field = ( split /\|/, $value )[4];
```